# Oracle Clusterwave Control is not found

Tags: database, oracle

I am using Oracle DB 19c on Windows and trying to create an ASM instance. I am following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYqnUzWY86s
However, once I run `startup`, I get the following:

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
ORA-29701: unable to connect to Cluster Synchronization Service
```

I googled the second error and found out that I need to run `crsctl config has`. However, I don't have a file named crsctl nowhere in the Oracle folders. And therefore I can't run the command:

```
'crsctl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: RAC on Windows: How to Install Grid Infrastructure 19c (19.1.X) and RAC on Windows (Step by Step) (Doc ID 2669386.1)
Last updated on NOVEMBER 22, 2021

Comment: The ASM instance should be created automatically when you install Grid Infrastructure. It isn't something you do manually. The tutorial you were watching was over 10 years old, and not applicable to any current version of Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

General documentation for installing Oracle Clusterware 19c on windows is here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/riwin/index.html

You didn't provide your hardware and OS choice.
There's a compatibility matrix you have to follow, and it's quite strict:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/riwin/server-hardware-and-software-checklist-for-rac-installation.html#GUID-005BC7EB-A10A-4C50-A614-C658E9D3F8DF

The error you encountered could be do to a many things including what @pugzly pointed out (most probably).